# Input type=search width problem/bug in jQ Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

The width from the search bar in jquery mobile cannot be changed properly and the default width acts strange. How do I fix this?

Comment: acts strange ? cannot be changed properly ? ... please be more specific

Comment: @poelinca I'm sorry, I thought it was a more common and known problem. The thing is that the default width is 77% and when I change it to 100% it stretches out way too far. When I put it to about 95% it looks riht, but when I resize the window, it does not stretch out correctly, like it should when using percentages.

Comment: Please post some sample code where the issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the width is 100%.
Example:

```
<input type="search" name="itemcode" id="itemcode" value="" class="required" style="display: inline-block;  **width: 51%;** " width="13"/>;
```

The width 51% does have not effect (not the inline-block)!

So I had to override:

```
.ui-input-search{
    /*we may use a fielcontain with ID if we don't want to override for ALL*/
    width: 50%;<br>
}
```